# c++ inheritence base and sub class

Tags: c++

This is my base class Shape.h

```
#ifndef Shape_H
#define Shape_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    protected:
    string name;
    bool containsObj;

public:
    Shape();
    Shape(string, bool);
    string getName();
    bool getContainsObj();
    double computeArea();
};

   #endif
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include "Shape.h"

Shape::Shape(string name, bool containsObj)
{
    this -> name = name;
    this -> containsObj = containsObj;
}
string Shape:: getName()
{
return name;
}
bool Shape::getContainsObj()
{
    return containsObj;
}
```

and this is my sub class. Cross.h

```
#ifndef Cross_H
#define Cross_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Shape.h"
using namespace std;

class Cross: public Shape
{
protected:
    int x[12];
    int y[12];
public:
    Cross();
    double computeArea();

};

#endif
```

Cross.cpp

```
#include "Cross.h"

Cross::Cross()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        this -> x[i] = 0;
        this -> x[0] = 0;
    }

}
```

Shape and Cross are in different files, but inside the same folder. The weird thing is when i compile this, errors that i have never seen before came up such as "In function 'ZN5CrossC1Ev', undefined reference to Shape::Shape(),'ZN5CrossC1Ev', undefined reference to Shape::Shape(), undefined reference to WinMain@16".

I tried to do some debugging myself. When i remove the Cross constructor, it works fine. But i definitely need it. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Are the parts you wrapped in `#ifdef`s in separate header files, while the code is in source (.cpp) files?  It looks like you're having linker issues likely stemming from compiling the headers as source.

Comment: Unrelated: Do *not* put `using namespace std;` in header files. While it may seem convenient, it will one-day come back to bite you. Fully qualify your standard library namespace objects in headers (and everywhere else, if at-all-feasible).

Comment: Also kinda unrelated: you didn't include `<string>`, while it may be included by `<iostream>` its a better idea to include `<string>` too in case you remove `<iostream>` and then forget to include other dependencies (such as `string`).

Comment: You presumably want `computeArea()` to be a `virtual` member function. Otherwise, there seems little point in your design.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't define the default constructor but you declared it `Shape();`. The only constructor you defined is the one with `string` and `bool` parameters `Shape(string, bool);`.

adding

```
Shape::Shape()
{
}
```

or removing

```
Shape();
```

will fix it.

---

For future debugging read the error more carefully, it explains exactly whats wrong:

```
undefined reference to Shape::Shape()
```

Comment: Hi, i did what you told me, i took out Shape(); I now have different error, no matching function for call to Shape::Shape () that points me to Cross:: Cross (), candidates are ShapeTwoD(string, bool);

Comment: @June Try adding the definition if taking out the declaration doesn't work. The reason it may not like taking it out is because constructing `Cross` also calls the constructor of `Shape`, the way to do it without defining a default constructor for `Shape` is to change `Cross::Cross() { ... }` to `Cross::Cross() : Shape(some-string, some-bool) { ... }` so it calls the complex constructor instead.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared a default constructor for `Shape`, but not defined it anywhere. The default constructor for `Cross` uses it implicitly to initialise its base class.

You options are:

- Define the constructor, if you want `Shape` to be default-constructible;
- Otherwise, remove the declaration and get `Cross` to initialise `Shape` with the other constructor.